# Top generous users—users that spend their reputation in bounties

Tags: support, reputation, bounty, data-explorer

I just came across an interesting user who has more gold badges than most top 20 users. The low reputation of below 10,000 made me wonder how that's possible. I found out that he's continuously spending his reputation on bounties.

Would someone mind building a SEDE query that allows us to find the top generous users on Stack Overflow, i.e. those that spent most reputation in bounties?

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/207278/top-20-most-generous-users-bounties-awarded-vs-total-reputation

Comment: I wonder why I didn't find it - seems so obvious now

Comment: The SEDE explorer isn't exactly an obvious place to look - I found it through Google...

Comment: Here is another query that more accurately does what you want (without the "percentage of user's rep" factor) http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/258280/top-n-investors

Comment: He is the most rational economic actor here. There is nothing else you can spend it on, and hoarding it isn't rational unless you expect a seriously rainy day :-|

Comment: @EJP -  I think that makes alot of sense. At some point, you think "well, might as well use it for something". You only *need* about 100 rep just to have basic privileges. use the rest for bounties !

Comment: @Pekka웃 my god... those subqueries...

Comment: @coffee being able to review most things, edit without needing approval and being able to close vote are also nice privileges though, I'd keep the minimum rep you hoard slightly over 3k :)

Comment: Spend it where you Earn it!!

Comment: I expected you to ask if we can make a badge for that.  Would be nice.

Comment: @BAR: done: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307772/introduce-generous-and-selfless-badge

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Thanks to [Pekka](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/187606/pekka-%ec%9b%83), I have created [the following query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/372216/479627/top-20-most-generous-users-bounties-awarded) and that user shows as number 1 on the list:

```
-- Show top 20 most generous users: bounties awarded
-- Minimum of 50 reputation required (removes low rep users, Community and
-- sin-binned users)

SELECT
  TOP(20)
  Users.Id [User Link],
  Users.DisplayName,
  Users.Reputation,
  (SELECT SUM(BountyAmount) FROM Votes WHERE Votes.UserId = Users.Id) as TotalBountiesAwarded
FROM Users
WHERE
  (SELECT SUM(BountyAmount) FROM Votes WHERE Votes.UserId = Users.Id) > 0 -- ensure a bounty has been awarded
  -- exclude Community and sin binned users
  -- minimum amount here to qualify for this?
  AND Users.Reputation >= 50 
ORDER BY 
  TotalBountiesAwarded DESC
```

Here is [leora](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4653/leora): 192 gold badges but less than 10,000 reputation, having spent 51,000 in bounties (at the time of this answer)

[image: Top generous user]

Top 5 users (at the time of adding):

0. [leora](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4653), 51000 bounties, 9864 rep
1. [Peter Hosey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/30461), 21000 bounties, 75k rep
2. [Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53897), 19200 bounties, 44k rep
3. [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/376947), 17050 bounties, 7214 rep
4. [IAmYourFaja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/892029), 17000 bounties, 3169 rep

Considering gold badges of top 10 reputation users (at the time of adding)

0. Jon Skeet, 813k, 396 gold badges
1. Darin Dimitrov, 616k, 114 gold badges
2. BalusC, 600k, 157 gold badges
3. Hans Passant, 580k, 65 gold badges
4. Marc Gravell, 563k, 123 gold badges
5. VonC, 528k, 139 gold badges
6. CommonsWare, 504k, 58 gold badges
7. SLaks, 473k, 75 gold badges

only Jon Skeet is unreachable (of course!) and *leora* beats all others.

Comment: For the lazy, @leora has awarded 51000 in rep at the time of this comment.

Comment: I was hoping to see Jon Skeet on the list, awesome query though!

Comment: Jon Skeet has spent 100 reputation on bounties. Probably because bounties can be spent on questions only, and he doesn't have questions, he has answers.

Comment: The question is of course, how much bounty was set on own questions and questions of others.

Comment: Where did you get access to stackoverflow DB ?

Comment: @pavelkolodin: can you click the [link](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/372216/479627/top-20-most-generous-users-bounties-awarded) and then select "fork query"?  After that, look at "Revisions" to get a link to your question. That's how I did it.

Comment: @ArtjomB.: not exactly sure if something like [this](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/372254/479679/top-20-most-generous-unselfish-users-bounties-awarded) yields correct results.

Comment: @ThomasWeller: Bounties can also be placed on other users' questions.

Comment: Time to create a 'selfless' badge.

Comment: From [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/372289/users-with-gold-badges), there is actually [one user other than Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4639/edward-tanguay) who has more gold badges than leora.

Comment: This user is probably trying to stay below the 10000 reputation threshold to avoid annoyances (you get to see deleted posts if you have more than 10000 reputation)

Comment: Yes, but 173 of leora's gold badges are `Famous Question`, which are given out like cheap candy.  With the exception of its sibling, `Notable Question`, it's easier to get than all of the silver badges and, at that, more prolific than many (if not most) of the bronze badges... assuming you're asking questions in one of the more ridiculously popular tags (whose technologies are far more amply documented), of course.  Popular laziness badges ftw.  Not to diminish the overwhelming altruism of 50k rep in bounties, of course, but not all badges are equal...Great Answer >> Famous Question

Comment: Ah let's stay positive.  A badge is still a badge.

Comment: Nitpicking but your answer assumes Leora is male ("Here he is, leora: "), upvoted anywho :)

Comment: I would be furious that the bronze counter is stuck at 1023 though if I were in Leora's situation. So close.

Comment: @Sayse heh, all the Leoras I know are female

Comment: Just to continue on from the point above, [ranking the top gold badge holders](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/372430/users-ranked-by-gold-badges-including-question-and-answer-count), the questioners outnumber the answerers by more than 5:1, more so as you go down the list.  It seems to take about ten times the number of good answers to get a gold badge as it does for questions.  How's that for hard work...

Comment: Not a surprise to see Peter at #2. He's made a point of handing out bounties to tons of interesting unanswered questions: https://www.quora.com/What-does-it-feel-like-to-be-at-the-top-0-1-of-Stack-Overflow "Every December, I start dropping 500 (max)-rep bounties on good questions that have gone unanswered. The rest of the year, I star questions that look like good candidates for this treatment—questions that I don't know the answer to that are challenging enough to be likely to remain unanswered until December."

Comment: 174 famous questions asked, we should ask this user to write a guide for writing questions that new users can access or something

Comment: If you consider only bounties on others' questions, Peter is #1: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/372608/top-20-most-generous-users-bounties-awarded

Comment: @TravisJ The recipe is simple - pick a popular tag and ask short, clear, focused, easy to answer questions.  Hors D'Oeuvres, not Regency feasts.

Comment: @J... - You forgot choosing a title, which many people have issues with. Not only choosing a title, but choosing one which drove 10,000 visits 174 times is impressive. That alone lends itself to some want for insight. I would say .net is a popular tag, you yourself ask a clear question there which has been up for 4 years, and only 250 views. There is even a comment from you on your post about the ability to search for the post. I think making questions which are answerable is a topic which has been well covered, but findable is still an important aspect which imo could use more coverage.

Comment: @j08691 "Time to create a 'selfless' badge." (2) And make it **Platinum**!

Comment: @TravisJ I guess I should have put extreme emphasis on *easy to answer* - most famous questions are shockingly simple and easy to answer.

Comment: @ThomasWeller, Does your calculation include bounties offered to own questions or is it only limited to bounties offered to questions posted by other people?

Comment: Has anyone actually looked at leora's question history? She/he/it has asked a fantastic number of extremely low quality questions, e.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777257/how-do-you-create-a-yes-no-boolean-field-in-sql-server http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365407/c-sharp-code-to-validate-email-address The only reason she/he/it has been able to post so many bounties, is due to massive rep farming off these old questions. tl;dr `Famous Question` badge has zero correlation with question quality.

Comment: @Pacerier: my version counts all bounties (including self). [This](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/372608/top-20-most-generous-users-bounties-awarded) version is for bounties on stranger's questions only (excluding self). See also canon's answer

Comment: The same old Mystery User!!

Comment: @IanKemp My guess is that SO is changing. Back in the day those questions would have been normal to ask. Now they get closed within minutes. The thing is, SO became popular, the amount of users sky-rocketed and accepting more of these questions would only pollute it. This is my view of the matter.

Answer (score 28):

## All in one...

[This query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/376690/bounty-investors?spentWeight=1.0&pctWeight=1.5&OffsetRows=0&ReturnRows=10) includes amounts and percentages for reputation spent on one's self and on others. While an overall rank is included for context, results are ordered by a composite generosity rank which excludes self-serving bounties.

[image]

<sub>This particular query's top user is named [enough rep to comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3015232). He apparently retains enough rep to comment and burns the rest via bounties.</sub>

---

## Generous Bounty Investors

These queries exclude bounties offered on the user's own questions or any question to which the user has provided an answer.

#### Composite Ranking

Results for [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/376583/generous-bounty-investors?OffsetRows=0&ReturnRows=10) are ordered based on a composite ranking of total and percentage of rep spent.

[image]

#### Total Spent

Results for 
[this query][5] are ordered based on total rep spent:

[image]

## (Potentially Selfish) Bounty Investors

These queries can include bounties offered by the user on their own questions or questions to which they've provided an answer. So, these queries will include self-serving bounties.

#### Composite Ranking

Results for [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/376584/generous-bounty-investors?OffsetRows=0&ReturnRows=10) are ordered based on a composite ranking of total and percentage of rep spent.

[image]

#### Total Spent

Results for
[this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/372659/bounty-investors?OffsetRows=0&ReturnRows=20) are ordered based on total rep spent:

[image]

Comment: Interesting related query created from yours - http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/372905/480532/bounty-investors-by-rep-invested - Bounty Investors ordered by % invested rather than total spent with some additional constraints to avoid skew from low rep and suspended users

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/372659/bounty-investors?OffsetRows=0&ReturnRows=20