# Hundreds of questions, thousands of upvotes, only 500 rep

Tags: support, reputation, bounty, users, specific-user

A user with 500 rep had quite a few badges (86 gold). I found that somewhat unusual.

I checked his profile, and he has a plethora of well received content from over the years: questions with over 100 upvotes, answers with a good amount of votes. Some of his content dates back to [2009](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572547/what-does-static-mean-in-a-c-program/634035#634035), and he's [still active to this day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39808673/does-java-have-a-builtin-class-that-can-be-used-to-implement-a-hashtable).

With all this well received content, it amazes me that he has only 500 reputation. What could be the cause for this?

The user is [ant2009](https://stackoverflow.com/users/70942/ant2009?tab=profile).

Comment: 19450 reputation was spent on bounties by the user

Comment: The real Ant-Man. Playing it small!

Comment: Related: [Top generous users - users that spend their reputation in bounties](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/307512/3853934).

Comment: Well that definitely answers my question. Thanks @Gothdo for the link. I knew bounties were a candidate for quick rep depletion, but I would never expect one to knowingly deplete rep to the point of losing almost all privileges.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Take a look at the user's [profile page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/70942/ant2009?tab=bounties&sort=offered). They  used their reputation for bounties.